Erro no "sudo apt update"
sudo apt update
[sudo] senha para dell: 
Ign:1 https:ppa.launchpadcontent.net/atareao/lplayer/ubuntu lunar InRelease  
Ign:2 https:ppa.launchpadcontent.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Atingido:3 https:ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Err:4 https:ppa.launchpadcontent.net/atareao/lplayer/ubuntu lunar Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Err:5 https:ppa.launchpadcontent.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu lunar Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Obter:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease [126 kB]
Atingido:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease            
Obter:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9.164 B]
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto          
W: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/lunar/InRelease: Signature by key E1DD270288B4E6030699E45FA1715D88E1DF1F24 uses weak algorithm (rsa1024)
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu lunar InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/atareao/lplayer/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Atualizações a partir de tal repositório não podem ser feitas de forma segura e estão, portanto, desativadas por definição.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https:ppa.launchpadcontent.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Atualizações a partir de tal repositório não podem ser feitas de forma segura e estão, portanto, desativadas por definição.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'


the answer is in the text so please act upon it: for instance main/binary-1386/Packages  1(one)386 is NOT an architecture

Also remove repositories which don't have a release file.

This question is similar to: What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You post says you are using Ubuntu 23.04 this release is EOL and off topic on this site.
